# PHP redirect page based on URL sequence?

Tags: php, html, redirect

I'm looking to find a way to redirect a page with PHP to another url based on it's sequence, like so

```
http://example.com/re.php?=http://google.com
```

The page would redirect to **google.com**. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

url would be more like `http://example.com/re.php?url=http://google.com`

`re.php` would look something like:

```
header('Location: ' . $_GET['url']);
```

Just a guideline.

Comment: yep. Don't redirect to any page. Check the target! https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248799/check-if-web-page-ok-before-redirecting) might be relevant.